# Are there alternatives to slow screen-shoting with OpenGL ES?

Tags: android, opengl-es

In my application user must have an opportunity to take screen shots sometimes. To provide it I use the method shown below (actually OpenGL just draws into bitmap)

```
    private boolean drawToBmp()
    throws OutOfMemoryError {

    int b[]=new int[(int) (w*h)];
    int bt[]=new int[(int) (w*h)];
    IntBuffer buffer=IntBuffer.wrap(b);
    buffer.position(0);

    try {
        GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
        for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
                int pix = b[i * w + j];
                int pb = (pix >> 16) & 0xff;
                int pr = (pix << 16) & 0x00ff0000;
                int pix1 = (pix & 0xff00ff00) | pr | pb;
                bt[(h - i - 1) * w + j] = pix1;
            }
    }
    catch (GLException e) {
        return false;
    }
    scrShot = Bitmap.createBitmap(bt, w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    return true;
}
```

Unfortunately it works too slow. Are there any faster (and maybe cleaner) methods to provide screen shots (certainly, without any root modes for user)?

Comment: move the for loop into another thread

Comment: I my app the method described above actually works in its own thread. But the main thread must wait until the bitmap is taken because it is used at the next moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case your image is completely opaque (i.e., alpha is always 255), there is a trick to avoid the for loop:

- Create a buffer that is at least one byte larger than needed to hold the image
- Pass the buffer with one byte offset to glReadPixels
- Make the alpha value of the first pixel is set to 255 (that is the first byte of the buffer, which you skipped when calling glReadPixels)

Alternatively, have a look at this:
https://vec.io/posts/faster-alternatives-to-glreadpixels-and-glteximage2d-in-opengl-es